# How to use an angular custom element to another angular application

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have successfully created angular custom element named  in angular project and I want to use this custom element in another angular project
I tried using following ways:

- copied the `profile.js` file of custom element in another angular project and used in  tag of another project in `index.html`

> But getting error as GET http://localhost:4200/profile.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Index.html

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.1.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/profile.js"></script>


      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-profile></app-profile>
      <app-root></app-root> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for profile.js

Comment: where did you put the `profile.js` in the folder structure of the second Angular project? And how are you running the application - using `ng serve`?

Comment: And I moved profile.js into the dist folder of the second angular project and Yes, I am running application using ng serve still it is not working getting error as the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you put the `profile.js` file together with the source files of the Angular project. Try moving it into the `dist` folder (the folder where compiled files are placed, and from which the compiled application is served when you run `ng serve`)

Comment: I tried adding profile.js into the dist folder still getting error as  the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of profile.js,using main.js as the final concatenated file. I mean concatenate the contents of all the .js files into the main.js file.